# 'React/RCTDefines.h' file not found. In react native push notification integration

Tags: xcode, react-native, push-notification, react-native-ios

I am integrating push notification in my app. After following instructions 2 times (from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup)) again I am stuck in errors.
**Podfile**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

 platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'placementScript' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
   use_frameworks!

  # Pods for placementScript
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  target 'placementScript-tvOSTests' do
    #inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
    pod 'react-native-fcm', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fcm'

    pod 'RNReactNativeDocViewer', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-doc-viewer'

    pod 'RNFS', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fs'

    pod 'BVLinearGradient', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient'

    pod 'RNViewShot', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-view-shot'

  end

  target 'placementScriptTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

target 'placementScript-tvOS' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for placementScript-tvOS

  #target 'placementScript-tvOSTests' do
   # inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  #end

end
```

**When i build .xcodeproj**
- Errors are
[image]

- **and when i build using .xcworkspace**

  [image]

Can anybody help? Any reference to video/blog will also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set the search path to `recursive`. Click on your project in Xcode and follow this please:

build Settings > header search path > double click on it and click on + sign, 
then add the following path to it:

```
$(SRCROOT)/../../../ios/Pods
```

Also keep in mind that you have to make your push notification toggle on in capabilities in the Xcode.

finally close your terminals, clear(command+k) and rebuild it(command+R). 
Here are some sources:

https://medium.com/yale-sandbox/react-native-push-notifications-with-https://medium.com/yale-sandbox/react-native-push-notifications-with-firebase-cloud-functions-74b832d45386

https://ilirhushi.me/reactnative-push-notifications-firebase-ios/

I hope I could help. :)

Comment: @RajanLagah: Your welcome. Did you active the push notification in the capabilities in your Xcode?

Comment: @RajanLagah: Unfortunately there are not much materials in this special error, but I can provide you some material for push notification it self if you want.

Comment: that would be very helpful.

Comment: @RajanLagah: Thanks.